# Babies can only be born by killing mother?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember reading a book in which there is a female creature (I think an alien from another planet?) who is pregnant with several fetuses, and some humans come into contact with her, and at some point the humans are horrified to realize that the way the children will be born is by eating their way out of their mother, killing her. (I think the father may have been some sort of royalty, and this was a trend that was often repeated, with the upper/royal class completely not caring about the mother.) I vaguely remember this as being part of the "So You Want to be a Wizard" series, but can't seem to track it down and may be wrong...

Comment: This notion shows up in Card's [*Speaker For the Dead*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead), though I don't think the rest of the description matches that book particularly well.

Comment: It definitely sounds like SFTD: Ender shuddered and stood up. "That one is sterile, or else they never let her mate. She couldn't possibly have had children."

  "Why not?" asked Ouanda.

  "There's no birth canal," said Ender. "The babies eat their way out."

  Ouanda muttered a prayer.

  Ela, however, was more curious than ever. "Fascinating," she said. "But if they're so small, how do they mate?"

  "We carry them to the fathers, of course," said Human. "How do you think? The father's can't come here, can they?"

  "The fathers," said Ouanda. "That's what they call the most revered trees."

Comment: @Richard I see that you remember more of the book than I do. Why don't you make an answer of it.

Comment: Harry Turtledove's [*A World of Difference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_of_Difference_(novel)) has that alien-mothers-inevitably-die-in-childbirth theme, but they don't eat their way out, and there are no wizards involved as far as I can recall. There was also a Philip José Farmer novella on that theme. Of course neither of these is the book you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's in *[Wizards At War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_at_War)*.

Page 177

> There were things she herself was still finding uncomfortable about this particular species' take on reproduction... particularly what happened to the females after the many eggs they bore were fertilized. It brought to mind a particularly vivid sequence from a nature movie she'd seen on one of the educational channels last year-a wasp laying its egg inside some hapless caterpillar, which then went about its business until the day the egg hatched, and the wasp grub started eating its way out.
>   *That times a hundred*, Dairine thought. *Or a thousand. More workers, more warriors for the king. And as for the poor handmaiden, or what's left of her*—

Comment: Can you provide some detail for why you think that?

Comment: sounds right, as I really thought it was part of that series... can you elaborate?

Comment: @stumped In case you missed it, this answer has since been edited to elaborate more.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the novel "A World of Difference" by Harry Turtledove?  In it, as per the wiki link below the females always die during delivery. Though the fetuses do not actually eat their way out. They detach causing blood loss and death. In this particular story, the male mate of one of the females is an equivalent "royal".

> Females (referred to as "mates" by the Minervans) give birth to litters that consist of one male and five females, and the "mates" always die after reproducing because of torrential bleeding from the places where the six fetuses were attached; this gives a population multiplication of 5 per generation if all females live to adolescence and reproduce. Females reach puberty while still hardly out of childhood, and typically experience sex only once in the lifetime - leading to pregnancy and death at birth-giving.

[Fantastic Fiction](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/t/harry-turtledove/world-of-difference.htm)
[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_of_Difference_%28novel%29)

Comment: nope, never read that... And the little detail that I remember I'm quite sure of.

Answer (score 3):

Another novel with this kind of "mother dies due to offspring eating her" is at Phillip Jose Farmer's "The lovers". The protagonist leaves Earth (that is recovering from a biological attack that only a few nations survived, and whose nation is one of the superpowers -the other is the successor of Israel-) to a new planet.

Unexpectedly, she finds a female in the planet, only to learn that she is not fully human when she gets pregnant.

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Lovers-Philip-Jose-Farmer/dp/034528691X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034528691X)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a story in Larry Niven's "Known Space" / Ringworld universe - the reproduction of Pierson's Puppeteers works like that:

> Their cycle of reproduction is similar to that of Earth's digger
>   wasps: the Puppeteers consider themselves to have three genders (two
>   male, one female): the two "male" genders are the equivalent of human
>   female and male (one has an ovipositor, the other produces sperm) and
>   the "female" is a (non-sentient) parasitized host into which the ovum
>   and spermatozoon are deposited.

However, the Puppeteers do not have royalty and their attitude towards the females is not uncaring; their deaths are seen as a sad but unavoidable part of bringing forth new life.